# C++ named return value in function type signature?

Tags: c++

In codefights I see this piece of code.
https://codefights.com/challenge/CiuqqtLmCHMqFDfWL
The 116 char c++ solution.

```
std::vector<int> v, getCandyPosition(int N, int r, int c, int d) {
  return --d < N ? v = {d / (r * c) + 1,
                    r - (d / c) % r - 1,
                c - d % c - 1}
                 : v = {-1, -1, -1};
}
```

However when I try to compile it with `g++ --std=c++11 src` with

`#include <vector>` on top. It complains with

```
“error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
std::vector<int> v, getCandyPosition(int N, int r, int c, int d) {”
```

So

1. Is the function type signature legitimate c++? If so can you please point me to some documentation as I lack the keywords to search for the correct resources.
2. How may I compile with this syntax?

Comment: Please post a link to the actual code on codefights (or copy and paste more of the relevant part of the code).

Comment: `std::vector<int> foo, bar(void);` is valid: you're declaring a variable  and a function prototype at the same time. But I don't think you're allowed to define the function in that line. Presumably you have a compiler extension? Also, I'm not sure about the way you assemble the return vector. That's *certainly* a compiler extension. By the way, nothing wrong with the question IMO; +1.

Comment: @Bathsgeba The vector is just being assigned from an initialiser list, which looks legit.